# r Permission denied loading gganimate

Tags: r, failed-installation, gganimate

follow my previous question, now I am able to manually download `gganimate` and unzip to my PC. When I try to load `h` package, there is an error:

```
shell("R CMD build gganimate")
```

> - checking for file 'gganimate/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
> - preparing 'gganimate':
> - checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
> - checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
> - checking for empty or unneeded directories
> - building 'gganimate_0.9.9.9999.tar.gz'
>     Warning in gzfile(tarfile, "wb", compression = compression_level) :
>     cannot open compressed file 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/gganimate_0.9.9.9999.tar.gz',
>
> probable reason 'Permission denied'
>   Error in gzfile(tarfile, "wb", compression = compression_level) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>   Execution halted
>
> Warning message:
>   In shell("R CMD build gganimate") :
>     'R CMD build gganimate' execution failed with error code 1

Tried to turn off antivus, but it won't help:

```
trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip, quote(Sys.sleep(2)), at = which(grepl("Sys.sleep", 
      body(utils:::unpackPkgZip), fixed = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I have zero problems installing the package using `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/gganimate")` and R 3.5.1. You might want to try re-installing R. Also make sure that you have RTools installed as at least one of `gganimate`'s dependencies needs compilation.

Comment: my corporate cannot install from GitHub, so have to do it manually